# Proper way to collect values from flow in android and coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am new to  Kotlin Coroutines and flow. I am using datastore to store some boolean data and the only way to read data from datastore is using flow according to documentation.

I have this code in my ViewModel

```
fun getRestroProfileComplete(): Boolean {
        var result = false
        viewModelScope.launch {
            readRestroDetailsValue.collect { pref ->
                result = pref.restroProfileCompleted
            }
        }

       Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "getRestroProfileComplete outside: $result")
        return result
    }
```

And in my fragments onCreateView method this code

```
if(restroAdminViewModel.getRestroProfileComplete()){
       
        Log.d(TAG, "Profile Completed")
        profileCompleted(true)
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Profile not completed ")
        profileCompleted(false)
    }
```

Sometimes I get the data from datastore other times it is always false.

I know that the getRestroProfileComplete method function does not wait for the launch code block to complete and gives a default false results.

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Your view-model should present a flow (or similar) to the view with the boolean value.

Comment: You've created a race condition where the coroutine probably isn't finished collecting the first value by the time your function returns. See here for explanation and solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370029/506796

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are launching an asynchronous coroutine (with launch) and then, without waiting for it to do its job, you return whatever is in the result variable. Sometimes the result will be set, sometimes it won't, depending on how long datastore takes to load the preference.

If you need the preference value in a non-coroutine context then you must use `runBlocking`, like this:

```
fun getRestroProfileComplete(): Boolean {
        val result = runBlocking {
            readRestroDetailsValue.collect { pref ->
                pref.restroProfileCompleted
            }
        }

       Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "getRestroProfileComplete outside: $result")
        return result
    }
```

However, that's not a good thing to do at all! You should expose a flow and consume that flow from the fragment, so you don't block the main thread and your UI can react to preference changes.

```
fun getRestroProfileComplete(): Flow<Boolean> {
    return readRestroDetailsValue.map { pref ->
        pref.restroProfileCompleted
    }
}
```

and in your fragment's onCreateView you launch a coroutine:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    restroAdminViewModel.getRestroProfileComplete().collect { c ->
        if(c) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Profile Completed")
            profileCompleted(true)
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Profile not completed ")
            profileCompleted(false)
        }
}
```

(This will keep monitoring the preference, you can do other things with the flow, like get the first `true` element with `.first { it }`)

Comment: Great answer @niqueco, I feel in the fragment's onCreateView, it would be good to collect using `launch` and using `repeatOnLifeCycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)`, this performs the necessary job cancellations when app goes to background and restart collection when the app reaches onStart again, which saves a lot of resource.

Comment: Question (also new to Kotlin+Android+Coroutines): Is this creating a memory leak? As the block is bound to the fragment object (can access the fragment properties, call the fragment methods, ...). Or is it by some magic unregistered by the lifecycleScope as soon as the fragment is wiped?

Comment: Yes, @JiříKřivánek, exactly. That's why it's a "scope". All coroutines created inside that scope are cancelled when that scope is cancelled, and `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` is tied to the lifetime of that fragment.